# Building Nexus 6 (shamu) kernel with module load enabled

Tags: kernel-module, android-kernel

I need to modify Shamu msm kernel to enable loading of driver modules.
When i try using the below flags in shamu_defconfig, I get build errors.

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
```

Is there any dependency for enabled module load in Shamu kernel ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `make menuconfig` command to enable loadable modules. It will follow all required dependencies for you.